# How do I delete text when I press a button? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to make a script that can by the click of a button choose randomly an even or an odd number and then tell you if it was even or odd. But I can't make it delete the text after I press the button so it just puts the text below. Sry If my message is unclear

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()
root.geometry("960x540")

def numberTeller():

    randomNumber = random.randint(1,2)

    if (randomNumber%2) == 0:
        evenOrOdd = Label(root, text="Even")
        evenOrOdd.pack()
    else:
        evenOrOdd = Label(root, text="Odd")
        evenOrOdd.pack()

button = Button(text="Click for random even or odd",font=("robotto",27),command=numberTeller)

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WELDU.png <-- Image link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new label, create one label and then just `config`ure it as needed:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label
import random


def number_teller():
    random_number = random.randint(1, 2)
    if random_number % 2 == 0:
        even_or_odd.config(text='Even')
    else:
        even_or_odd.config(text='Odd')


root = Tk()
root.geometry("960x540")

button = Button(
    text="Click for random even or odd", font=("robotto", 27),
    command=number_teller)

even_or_odd = Label(root)

button.pack()
even_or_odd.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Also:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations. Object method definitions have one blank line around them.

Comment: _"..you definitely don't need to import `time`.."_: `time` can not only be used for `sleep`, it can be used for `time.time` and so on too....

Comment: @CoolCloud you're right, it can be used for other purposes, my first thought was just `sleep`. I removed that part from the answer